# django python package for app

Tags: django

We want to create django apps outside of the project directory.

Do we need to create a python package by creating setup.py and install it into the site-packages?

How does this work when in app is embed in the project folder? (I don't see a setup.py anywhere).

I guess I am not understanding when to make a package and when not to.

Comment: do you want to distribute it separately or do you just want a separate project for some app's?

Comment: see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457511/creating-a-redistributable-django-app)

Comment: I want the apps to be separate from the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just include an app from an external location I normally use the following:

```
main
  -__init__.py
  -manage.py
  -urls.py
  -settings.py
  -foo
    -__init__.py
    -models.py
    -views.py
    -admin.py

external
  -__init__.py
  -bar
    -__init__.py
    -models.py
    -views.py
    -admin.py
```

Lets say we want to include `external.bar` as an app in the django project `main`.

First make sure that in the `settings.py` of `main` `external` is on the `sys.path` so python can find it:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/external")
```

Then just add `external.bar` to the installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.stuff',
    'main.foo',
    'external.bar',
)
```

Then `admin.auto_discover()` should find your `external.bar` app and load the admin for it.